# From excel, in vba, get Id of current shape selected in powerpoint

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I work from excel, and i open several powerpoint in a loop inside a directory, in vba. 
While i run the macro (from excel), I make a loop within every shape inside every slides in powerpoints presentation.

I stop the macro to see if AutoShapeType = -2, and i select it in vba just to check visualy if the shape is the right shape i want. 
Otherwise, if the selected shape doesn't seems right, I select it manually and I want to know how the syntaxe to get the id of the current selected shape, in order to name it.

```
Set PPtapp = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")
PPtapp.Visible = True
Dim sld As Slide
Dim numslide As Long
Dim nbslide As Long
Dim WVL_CptShape As Integer

'list of every powerpoint path
ppt = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Template").Range("A" & i).Value

For i = 2 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Template").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Set PptDoc = PPtapp.Presentations.Open(ppt)
    With PptDoc
        For Each sld In PptDoc.Slides
            For WVL_CptShape = 1 To .Slides(sld.SlideNumber).Shapes.Count
                WVL_Id = .Slides(sld.SlideNumber).Shapes(WVL_CptShape).ID
                If PptDoc.Slides(sld.SlideNumber).Shapes(WVL_CptShape).AutoShapeType = -2 Then
                    'I select the shape to see visualy if it's a good selection and I stop the macro
                    PptDoc.Slides(sld.SlideNumber).Shapes(WVL_CptShape).Select
                    Stop
                    'if the selection doesnt seems right I select the right shape manualy
                    'Question : in vba, i want to change the name of the selected shape. 
                    'But i don't know how to get the id of the current selected shape (see below : ID_OF_CURRENT_SHAPE_SELECTED_MANUALY)
                    'I would like to rename it, in order to recognize it easily next time
                     PptDoc.Slides(sld.SlideNumber). Shapes(ID_OF_CURRENT_SHAPE_SELECTED_MANUALY).Selection.Name = "Myshape"
                end if
            Next WVL_CptShapeNext 
        sld.Close 
    End With
Next
PPtapp.Quit
Set PPtapp = Nothing
```

Comment: Are you looking for a method how to read the Shape.Type for all shapes in all slided ?

Comment: I am looking for an instruction, that get selected shape : I loop all the shape, if 1 shape (e.g. shape ID 1) is AutoShapeType = -2 i stop the macro. If this shape isn't the shape i was looking for. I select another shape (e.g. shape ID 2) (manualy on the slide), and i want the macro to get that new one id shape (shape ID 2). thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    Set PptDoc = PPtapp.Presentations.Open(ppt)
    With PptDoc
        For Each sld In PptDoc.Slides
            For WVL_CptShape = 1 To sld.Shapes.Count
                WVL_Id = sld.Shapes(WVL_CptShape).ID
                If sld.Shapes(WVL_CptShape).AutoShapeType = -2 Then
                    'I select the shape to see visualy if it's a good selection and I stop the macro
                    sld.Shapes(WVL_CptShape).Select
                    Stop

' And to change the name of the shape:
sld.Shapes(WVL_CptShape).Name = "New name for shape"
' or better, in case you selected a different shape:
```

ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Name = "New name for shape"

In this type of situation, you want to work with the shape's Index, not its ID.

Note that you can iterate through the shapes collection on a slide just as you can iterate through the slides collection in a presentation.  It makes the code a lot simpler to write and to follow:

```
Set PptDoc = PPtapp.Presentations.Open(ppt)
With PptDoc
    For Each sld In PptDoc.Slides
        For each shp in sld.shapes
            If shp.AutoShapeType = -2 Then
                'I select the shape to see visualy if it's a good selection and I stop the macro
                shp.Select
                Stop
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge. I have an issue by using the ActiveWindow method. I use Excel 2007 in Windows 7 Enterprise. Should i declare something before ?

Comment: The actual situation is, no matter what i select in the slide, the macro rename the shape before the stop instruction. Thank you :)

Comment: Edit your original post to include the current version of your code and indicate what the "issue" you mention is and what line of code it happens on.  Include the exact text of any error messages you see.